# Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'CheerioElement'

Tags: typescript, cheerio

Why does TypeScript warn that `Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'CheerioElement'`?

```
async function inlineImages(serializedSvg: string) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(serializedSvg);

  await Promise.all(
    Array.from($('image[href^="http"]')).map(async (el: CheerioElement) => {
      const url = el.attr("href"); // <--- HERE
      if (!url) {
        return;
      }

      const data = await requestBase64(url);
      if (!data) {
        return;
      }
      el.attr("href", data); // <--- AND HERE
    })
  );

  return serializedSvg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives this warning because the way that 'CheerioElement' is typed, it has no 'attr' property.

```
interface CheerioElement {
    // Document References
    // Node Console
    tagName: string;
    type: string;
    name: string;
    attribs: { [attr: string]: string };
    children: CheerioElement[];
    childNodes: CheerioElement[];
    lastChild: CheerioElement;
    firstChild: CheerioElement;
    next: CheerioElement;
    nextSibling: CheerioElement;
    prev: CheerioElement;
    previousSibling: CheerioElement;
    parent: CheerioElement;
    parentNode: CheerioElement;
    nodeValue: string;
    data?: string;
    startIndex?: number;
}
```

Referencing the typings available at: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cheerio/index.d.ts

'attr' is a property of the 'Cheerio' type, which is what the invokation of 'CheerioStatic' `$()` returns